# PHPMailer does not give error message?

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Im creating a little Email Script at the Moment with PHPMailer + SMTP Authentication. I tried now sending an E-Mail using a wrong Passwort - but it still gives back "true" for success... anyone have any idea?`

Here is My Function, that i use to call sendmail:

```
$erfolg_email = true;
    foreach($empfaenger as $value)
    {

        $response = $this->sendMail($smtp, $value, $content, $files);
        if($response != true)
        {

            return $response;
            $erfolg_email = false;

        }

    }
```

And here is my PHPMailer Function

```
function sendMail($smtp, $empfaenger, $content, $attachements)
{

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

    try{

        $mail->IsSMTP();    
        $mail->Host = $smtp['SMTP'];
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;     // turn on SMTP authentication
        $mail->Port = $smtp['Port'];
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        if($smtp['Domain'] != '')
        {

            $username = $smtp['Username']."@".$smtp['Domain'];

        }else
        {

            $username = $smtp['Username'];

        }
        $mail->Username = $username;  // SMTP username
        $mail->Password = $smtp['Password']; // SMTP password
        $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
            'ssl' => array(
                'verify_peer' => false,
                'verify_peer_name' => false,
                'allow_self_signed' => true
            )
        );
        $mail->From = $smtp['Email_Address'];
        $mail->AddAddress($empfaenger);
        $mail->WordWrap = 50;
        $mail->isHTML(true);

        foreach($attachements as $value)
        {

            $mail->AddAttachment($value);

        }
        $mail->Subject = "Mahnung";
        $mail->Body = $content;
        $mail->AltBody = "Sie haben offene Posten";

        if($mail->Send() == true)
        {

            echo $mail->ErrorInfo;
            return $mail->ErrorInfo;

        }else
        {

            return $mail->ErrorInfo;

        }

    } catch (phpmailerException $e) {

        return $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer

    } catch (Exception $e) {

        return $e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!

    }
}
```

$smtp contains an array with all the SMTP INformation, Email address, Signature, Smtp Server, Port, Username, Password and SSL Usage...

I am pretty sure, I am using the wrong username and password, as no Email is getting through - but i still get "true" as a result of the send mail function... its not even echoing the error. I did even try to give an Error Message, when sending is successfull... But nothing

Any help is apreciated!

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `sendMail` doesn't return a boolean. Since it's an array / object the result is always `true` in this case. Try printing `$response` before your if statement and you will see the error.

Comment: The Error is a String... Can I check the return value with "is_bool()" ?

Comment: OK - I got it. It seems to be important to check the return values of all functions with "is_bool". That helped me, getting the right decisions what to do with the return value

Comment: It's not so much that you need to use `is_bool`, it's that you need to pay attention to your return types in general. `$mail->ErrorInfo` will never be a boolean, so checking its value as one will achieve nothing whether the call succeeds or not.

Answer (score 0):

In your php mailer function file itself you can add this coding at the last:

```
$send = $mail->Send(); //Send the mails
    if($send){
        echo '<center><h3>Mail sent successfully</h3></center>';
    }
    else{
        echo '<center><h3>Mail error: </h3></center>'.$mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
}
```